Show about a a guy being chased by a TV set?
Saw this a a kid, so 70's or earlier, maybe Twilight Zone or OL or similar? Guy trying to get rid of an old TV set, the kind with long spindly legs (like the kind I watched the show on!) that kept finding it's way home...actually saw it chasing him like a huge spider...gave me nightmares for years! Can't find anything online about it...anyone??
edit: Thinking back now...maybe it was a comedy...?;)

Did it have any other moving machines?  Your question put an image in my mind of a self-moving vacuum cleaner.

My memory is imperfect, there could have been more to the story...all I really remember is him driving the thing way out of town and dumping it, only to have it scuttle after him like a big black spider. (shudder). There was an Outer Limits episode where a guy was attacked by his appliances, but I don't think it's related to my memory...

Also a longshot, but it could be the movie "The Twonky" (1953), based on a short story of the same name, which features a man buying a television that is actually from far into the future.  It starts attempting to control his life in various ways (implying that the far future is a totalitarian "nanny state" and won't let citizens smoke or do anything unhealthy, even if it has to lobotomize people to do it).  
He does attempt to throw the TV away on several occasions, including by driving it away and leaving it, but it always returns.
It didn't look quite like a big, black spider, though, but rather like this:


We're talking 50 years ago now, and our memories change with time. Although I remember it differently (the set I watched it on was the set I remember from the movie, but that's just...well, a child's memory...), I think you may have nailed it. I "did" thing for a long time that it was a movie, but then I decided that it was a pretty thin concept to pull out to movie length and it must have been a serial episode. Must find it somewhere and see! Thanks so much!

After reading more on IMDB and Wiki, I'm sure this is the movie. It WAS a comedy, and I remember more of it now after reading the synopsis. Good ID, thanks so much!!

@dogteam No problem!  You might want to click the checkmark (next to the up/down votes) so that it marks the question as 'solved' when others look at the list.

Long shot because it's not a neat fit:  There was a Twilight Zone episode aired on October 28, 1960 called A Thing About Machines.  But it has all sorts of devices moving.

As I said above, you're right...it doesn't fit neatly with what I remember, but that's on me. I think this fits! Thank you all!
